# Minecraft server laggy or time out only when on 5ghz connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, minecraft

My friends have a minecraft server and I can normally play on it with a 2.4ghz wifi connection with no problems but whenever I use a 5ghz connection I either get timed out or the game is extraordinarily laggy.

Normally my 5ghz connection is much faster than the 2.4ghz connection on everything else and I have no problems.

It's a pain to switch between connections as I usually forget whenever I launch minecraft. If somebody could help me figure it out that would be much appreciated.